# Distribution of computations to different cores

Tags: ios, parallel-processing

I have a program that has multiple computations that a very reliant on time meaning that i need the computations to be handled almost at the same time.

I am refering to the iphone 4s - 5s dual core processor.  Is there a way that i can delegate certain computations to certain cores in the processor?  For example, if i have two computations (1c and 2c) that are very reliant on time and i need them to be executed together, can i run computation 1c on the "left" core and 2c on the "right" core?

I've read a little about parallel processing but I cannot find anything about it for ios development.  If somebody could point me in the right direction or answer this directly i would appreciate it a lot! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `very reliant on time`? Why are they like that?

Comment: Perhaps the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) would be a good start.

Comment: Use grand central dispatch (GCD) to spread work among the cores. GCD is well designed and easy to use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch

Comment: @Wain Im using multiple native device features that use algorithms that work together so i can find one precise piece of information im looking for.  However, these native device features are supplementing values every 20ms or so(whatever i find the optimal sampling time to be) and i need to run these functions simultaneously in order for this to function properly.

Comment: Management of cores is the job of the operating system.  The most you can do is try to specify a high priority pthread or dispatch queue and hope your operations execute on two cores.

Comment: Why are you not getting a consistent set of source data and then starting the tasks with that. Then get a new consistent set for the next run...

Comment: @Wain I am but then I need to use that source data(which is coming from "native features group 1") in simultaneous computations to produce data that is used by a different group of native features, "native features group 2" which includes the camera, to produce a real time user experience

Comment: Sounds like a job for an operation queue with dependencies.